# Give Access to Azure SQL Database to MS Access application

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I created a MS Access application that link to Azure SQL Database using SQL account. My setup works well and I sometimes have to create a new firewall rules to connect because I am on a DHCP client machine. Now I need to connect other people to the database and I need guidance. I created an Azure AD then add one test person to start with. I tried to create a VPN but was not able to make it work. What are the options available to have other people to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to give access to Azure SQL database add external user to Active directory by following this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal). If you have multiple users, then create a group and add users to the group. You need to enable AD authentication in Azure SQL server.
Go to Azure Active Directory admin and set Azure AD user or group as admin.

[image]

[image]

After successful completion of setting Admin, you will be able to access Azure SQL database with Azure AD credentials.